# Set next node of an instruction in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm

1:   %mul2 = fmul float %1, %1

2:   %mul3 = fmul float %mul2, %1

3:   %mul4 = fmul float %mul3, %1

4:   %mul5 = fmul float %mul4, %1

5:   %mul6 = fmul float %mul5, %1

6:   %mul7 = fmul float %mul6, %1

7:   store float %mul5, float* %x, align 4, !tbaa !0

I want to set the next node of %mul5 to %mul7. getNextNode() function gives the next node as %mul6(which I want to delete). Is there any function to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

getNextNode() is an internal implementation details of stuff deep inside LLVM API. You should never use it. Use the standard LLVM API to manipulate the list of instructions: iterators and IRBuilder. See http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#simplechanges and http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html for more information.

Also, before deleting %mul6 you have to replace all uses of it.

Comment: I have used replaceAllUsesWith() to replace all uses of it. I am not able to delete mul6 and mul7 since it is still linked to the previous instruction mul4. I get a StackDump after deleting mul7 and mul6 in the same order since there is a dependency. Please suggest how to delete mul6 and mul7.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the proper way of handling deletion with dependencies?