# How to get the next immediate instruction for a given instruction?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am looking for a right way to get a next immediate instruction that follows a given instruction.

Let's assume that I have the following:

```
%10 = icmp slt i32 %8, %9
br i1 %10, label %11, label %17
```

I have a

```
  CmpInst *cmpInst = dyn_cast<CmpInst>(&V);
```

which corresponds to `%10`.

How do I get an access to the `BranchInst` that follows my `CmpInst`?

I assume that a solution should take both cases into account: when there is a next instruction and when there is no one i.e. it is the end of a `BasicBlock`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turned out to be as simple as this:

```
Instruction *instruction = cmpInst->getNextNode();
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous answer `cmpInst->getNextNode()`, which appears in several projects I have seen.

However, according to another answer in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062782/set-next-node-of-an-instruction-in-llvm-ir), the `getNextNode()` is an internal implementation details of stuff deep inside LLVM API. Thus, I prefer to using `cmpInst->getNextNonDebugInstruction()`, which could skip intrinsic instructions such as `call void @llvm.dbg.declare(...)`.